# The Constraint Entry 'httpMethod' on the Route Must Have a String Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httpserver, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an asp.net Web API project, and in my `WebApiConfig` file, I have the following route defined:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Web API Get",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
    defaults: new { action = "Get" },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
    );
```

For integration testing purposes, I want to make a request to an `HttpSelfHostServer` to verify that we are receiving the proper data back from the api call. I am making the `HttpRequestMessage` as follows:

```
var httpMethod = new HttpMethod("GET");
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, "http://localhost:XXXX/api/User/");
var results = _client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

I would expect that this would call the Get method on the UserController and then return the results as defined in that method. However, I instead get the following exception:

**System.InvalidOperationException: The constraint entry 'httpMethod' on the route with route template 'api/{controller}' must have a string value or be of a type which implements 'IHttpRouteConstraint'**

This same url (`http://localhost:XXXX/api/User/`) works without error when I use it in the browser, so I am pretty sure the issue has to be in the way I am sending the request to the `HttpSelfHostServer` through the `HttpClient`. I have tried using the `HttpMethod.Get` constant instead, but that also threw the same error.

Does anyone have any idea how I could resolve this issue?

Comment: this might help you http://emilsblog.lerch.org/2012/05/constraint-for-route-parameter.html

Comment: I don't have access to the WebApi Url object to use the solution he is proposing. I see that the route direction is likely RouteDirection.UrlGeneration and httpMethod is not being found (hence the exception). How can I get the httpMethod with a string value of "GET" into my request without using the Url.Action() method?

Comment: Okay, I came across the UrlHelper class which seems to do the same thing as the Url object in the controllers. However, now I am getting a new error associated with the configuration object. I'll update my question shortly with more details...

Comment: Oops, configuration object was null at that point. After fixing that I'm back to where I started with the first exception.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the [`proper type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routing.httpmethodconstraint%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for your constraint:

```
constraints: new { httpMethod = new System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
```

I guess you were using [`System.Web.Routing.HttpMethodConstraint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.httpmethodconstraint.aspx) which is an entirely different class used for ASP.NET MVC routing and which has nothing to do with ASP.NET Web API routing.

Comment: Wow, yeah that was it. Thank you, I've been beating my head against that one for a while now.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft created one hell of a mess when they duped every single class for this Web API that was available in MVC but under different assemblies and namespaces. It's a very common cause for mistakes.

Comment: Great answer, that was really well spotted @DarinDimitrov, thanks.

Comment: I ended up here because I was looking for the opposite, incase this is useful to anyone else:  `new System.Web.Routing.HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Delete.ToString())`