# Why does my POST request call my defined GET function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, controller, webapi

I am using ASP.NET Web Api, and I have setup a route that should handle both GET and POST. When I try to make a POST call, it comes back with this error

```
Response statuscode:'405'.
Response body: {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}
```

So it is trying to call the GET function rather than the POST function I have set up, even though I have registered them separately.

Here are my two functions

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
  [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
  public object GetApplicationFunc([FromUri]EmployeeApplicationDTO request)
  {
   //Do GET specific stuff 
  }

  [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
  public object PostApplicationFunc([FromBody]EmployeeApplicationDTO request)
  {
   //Do totally different POST stuff
  }
}
```

And then here is how I am registering the Routes

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "ApplicationGet",
routeTemplate: "application/apply",
defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "GetApplicationFunc"},
constraints: null);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "ApplicationPost",
routeTemplate: "application/apply",
defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "PostApplicationFunc"},
constraints: null);
```

So I have specified to different HTTP Routes, under the same 'routeTemplate' but only the "GetApplication()" is called, it acts like my "PostApplication()" does not exist when making a POST request. Why???

Comment: First route wins (i.e. you have defined the same route twice - so it just picks one of them and ignores the other one). You haven't constrained either route by post / get. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406158/34092

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your routes with these

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

actions

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
   Route[("{id}"]
  public object GetApplicationFunc( int id)
  {
   //Do GET specific stuff 
  }

  public object PostApplicationFunc( EmployeeApplicationDTO request)
  {
   //Do totally different POST stuff
  }
}
```

Assuming the employee Id=5  to use Get you need url http//..../employee/GetApplicationFunc/5

to post http//..../employee/PostApplicationFunc

Another way I could highly recommend is to use  route attributes

```
Route[("/Employee/GetApplication/id})"]
public object GetApplicationFunc( int id)
  {
   //Do GET specific stuff 
  }

Route[("/Employee/PostApplication")]
public object PostApplicationFunc( EmployeeApplicationDTO request)
  {
   //Do totally different POST stuff
  }
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. So I have seen this a lot of places ```{controller}/{action}/{id}``` but I have 60+ other routes with my RESTApi that probably wouldn't follow this design exactly. Does this mean I would have to completely redesign my entire RESTApi just to conform to ```{controller}/{action}/{id}``` ??

Comment: I could recomend to use attribute routing. See my updated answer. It is better than to put everything in one file.